# How to locate Bootstrap css/js files in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I am a php developer, though it's difficult to understand magento file structure.

Just now I have started to learn magento, but I couldn't find HTML Bootstrap files, can any one please help me how to locate files and where it will be in magento2.1.7?

[image: PLEASE HELP ME TO FIND LOCATION]

Comment: which theme you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

All CSS files are in their respective themes and compile to the `pub` folder. The Bootstrap is not a part of M2 by default, so the theme that you are using is bringing that in.

That theme will live in `app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/`. That is where the edits to these files will happen (the issue of setting up a child theme is a different question, but should be done instead of editing a theme's files directly). These edits will then be compile in the `pub/static/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/en_US/` folder (en_US if that is the language of the site you are building).

More to your question, in the inspector you are showing Bootstrap CSS files, but ask about bootstrap html files. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a CSS framework and there are not templates. So i'm i not understanding the question? The terms can get a little confusing since in M2 there are bootstrap files, but they are php classes use to initialize the application.

So let me know if i'm missing the mark on what you are asking with a little clarification.